"Not all there" found in MW wotd 2024 Dec. 17 as run-on sentence
https://www.merriam-webster.com/word-of-the-day/2024-12-17
lexical
// A dictionary provides lexical information—it tells you what the word "cat" means, not all there is to know about cats.
Imho, but should be added before not.
Another run-on sentences found in this dictionary column WOTD include then used as and then. (I have seen the usage in WOTD but forget where.)
However, then itself is an adverb, not a conjunction. It's considered a conjunctive adverb. And some other English sites also use this directly as conjunction from time to time.
I doubt the precision of the grammar, but MW is a famed dictionary.
Copypastas from MW:
not all there
idiom
informal
—used to describe a person who is somewhat strange or stupid
Her aunt is very sweet but not all there (mentally).
all there
adjective
1
: in full possession of one's mental faculties : SANE
behaved in such a way as to make one wonder if he was quite all there
—not often in formal use
2
slang : alert and well informed : QUICK-WITTED
wide-awake, alert, all there; he knows just where he is and what he means and where he is going
—Times Literary Supplement
The idiomatic meaning doesn't match the example sentence.
Re-edition:
Your parsing not (all there is to know about cats) is correct, and so is the structure tell A, not B. But I wonder in meaning, if a dictionary tells you lexical entries about cats and does not tell you that all there is to know about cats means the same with an example sentence. And is the noun clause (that) all there is to know about cats equivalent to the noun phrase the fact that the most part of the book focuses on cats? As the user points out, all there is to know about cats means every piece of information about cats. However, I don't agree that all there is to know about cats can exactly mean that. I think the sentence couched in the terms of not all there is a bit illogical if it means that. Hence I think, according to meaning instead of grammar, but it is still necessary before not all there in the example sentence. It's natural to say not most part of the book focuses on cats, but if (the fact that) not all there is to know about cats is something (the contents) a dictionary tells you, it's strange.

The word "but" does not need to be there. It is not a run on sentence.
The meaning is that:

A dictionary tells you A, not B

Where A is 'what the word "cat" means' and B is 'all there is to know about cats'. The two are noun phrases. They are alternatives, and you don't need "but" to separate them. The phrase "not all there" is irrelevant - you are trying to parse the sentence wrong.
'all there is to know about cats' means 'every piece of information about cats'

It can be thought of as the difference between "not (all there is to know about cats)" and "(not all there) is to know about cats". The correct parsing is the former. If someone intends the latter they will indeed need to include additional words.
